# Why pyautogui cannot find items in OSX Dock?

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui

I started to learn pyautogui for my personal project and almost instantly ran into the problems when trying to open OSX dock icons.

I want to open local Spotify which is under Mac Launchpad.

My code to do this.

```
import pyautogui

launchpad = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img/Launchpad.png')
```

This return `None` so the image was not found.

image example attached

[image]

However, if I open Mac OSX Notes window and paste the same image into it and ran the program again the image is found every time. Similarly, if I just leave image open in my Editor.

Is dock actually part of the OSX screen pyautogui can search from? If not how to interact with it?

Answer (score 3):

Figured that using application hotkeys vs find on the screen is a much less brittle approach. Below how I finally build Spotify bot.

```
import time

import pyautogui

# use pyauutogui key shortcut to open OSX spotlight search
pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'space')
# type spotify and press enter to open application
pyautogui.typewrite('Spotify')
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
# use Spotify keyboard shortcuts to select search.
# key docs here: https://support.spotify.com/ie/article/Keyboard-shortcuts/
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'l')
# typewrite allows passing string arguments using keyboard
pyautogui.typewrite('concentration music')
# move to select the song with tab and press enter to play
pyautogui.hotkey('tab', 'tab', 'tab', 'tab')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
pyautogui.hotkey('space')
# sleeps 30 seconds while music is playing
time.sleep(30)
pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'q')
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a program to pertaining your problem. It is a spotify bot aswell.

```
    import pyautogui as p
    from time import sleep as t

    p.keyDown("command")
    p.press("space")
    t(2)
    p.keyUp("command")
    p.typewrite("Spotify")

    p.press("enter")
    t(3)
    p.moveTo(153,132)
    p.click()
    t(1)
    p.typewrite("Never Gonna Give You Up")
    p.press("enter")

    p.moveTo(707,324)
    t(4)
    p.click()
    t(10)

    p.keyDown("command")
    p.press("q")
    t(1)
    p.keyUp("command")
```

The coordinates will be different pertaining to the position of your spotify window, so you can do p.mouseInfo/pyautogui.mouseInfo  to find the exact coordinates and substitute them in the code I gave above.